# Switch axis Y and Z in PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, matrix, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I would like to switch the Y and Z axis orientation in PyOpenGL. I have tried using matrix transformations but I have not been able to do it.

Code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(self.zoom, -self.zoom, -self.zoom, self.zoom, -5000, 5000)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glLoadMatrixf(self.m)
```

Where:

```
self.zoom = 150
self.m = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Wrong result:
[image]

Using identity matrix:
[image]

Expected:
[image]

Edit: This works:

```
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glOrtho(self.zoom, -self.zoom, -self.zoom, self.zoom, -5000, 5000)
        up = 1
        if self.theta == 360:
            up = -1
        gluLookAt(self.x, self.y, self.z, 0, 0, 0, 0, up, 0)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glLoadMatrixf(self.m)
```

Comment: *"[...] but I have not been able to do it."* - You've to be more specific. What exactly is the issue? The operations seems to be syntactically and semantically correct.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have added pictures of the result I get. The third one is edited using GIMP, it is not a real pic, it is what I would like to achieve

Comment: What you mean is that the call to `glLoadMatrixf(self.m)` works, but it doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, the elements in the scene are not rendered properly as you can see in the first pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2 dimensional vector can be rotated by 90°, by swapping the components and inverting one of the components:

- Rotate (x, y) left is (-y, x)
- Rotate (x, y) right is (y, -x)

What you actually do is to turn the right handed matrix to a left handed matrix. It is a concatenation of a rotation by 90° and mirroring.

Change the matrix:

Either

```py
self.m = [[1, 0,  0, 0],
          [0, 0, -1, 0],
          [0, 1,  0, 0],
          [0, 0,  0, 1]]
```

or

```py
self.m = [[1,  0, 0, 0],
          [0,  0, 1, 0],
          [0, -1, 0, 0],
          [0,  0, 0, 1]]
```

Note, the same can be achieved by a rotation around the x-axis. e.g:

```py
glLoadIdentity()
glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0)
```

---

If you've a view matrix and a model matrix, then you've to multiply the modle matrix to the view matrix by [`glMultMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml):

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
gluLookAt(self.x, self.y, self.z, 0, 0, 0, 0, up, 0)
glMultMatrixf(self.m)
```

Comment: Using the glRotate option I get the same result as picture 1, the perspective is wrong

Comment: I mean, Why do i get the 1st picture which is wrong instead of the thrid one?

Comment: No it is not. The perspective should remain unchanged

Comment: Why the glRotate(90, 1, 0, 0) is not equal to an axis rotation of 90 degrees around X axis?

Comment: the gluLookAt function was at the modelview matrix, it should be in the projection matrix, right?

Comment: @PepeElMago33 No, never! "look at" sets the view matrix!. So it is the 1st component of `GL_MODELVIEW`. But all the model transformation have to be done after "look at"

Comment: check edit, that works

Comment: Take into account that that lines get executed each frame, the matrix multiplication causes a weird rotational effect

Comment: Just found this: https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm

Comment: No it does not "cause a weird rotation effect" because of `glLoadIdentity()`