# Swap Y and Z Axis in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, mapping, transformation, opengl-compat

So basically i have created an application that renders a curve in a 2D-Dimension (X and Y). This application also uses a haptic device, which is represented as a cursor inside of the frame where the curve is also rendered.

The only thing i want to achieve is to map the y-axis of my projection to my z-axis of the haptic workspace of my haptic device. So basically i want to mantain the logic of the curve and cursor rendering and only change the used axis for my haptic workspace. I used this question: [Swap axis y and z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354346/switch-axis-y-and-z-in-pyopengl)

as a guidance. Practically i just have to use glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0) to achieve what i want. I tried rotating only the projection matrix of my haptic workspace, but this sadly doesnt work for me.

This is how my normal curve looks:
[image: Normal Curve]

Those are the results, while trying different options:
[image]

[image]

This is my code

reshapeCallback:

```
void reshapeCallback(int width, int height) {
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(minX, maxX, minY, maxY, -1, 11);
// glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0) [4th Try]
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
// glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0) [5th Try]

updateWorkspace();
}
```

updateWorkspace():

```
void updateWorkspace() {
GLdouble modelview[16];
GLdouble projection[16];
GLint viewport[4];

glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
//glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0) [2nd try]
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
//glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0) [1st try]
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

hlMatrixMode(HL_TOUCHWORKSPACE);
hlLoadIdentity();
//glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0) [3rd try]

// Fit haptic workspace to view volume.
hluFitWorkspace(projection);

// Compute cursor scale.
gCursorScale = hluScreenToModelScale(modelview, projection, viewport);
gCursorScale *= CURSOR_SIZE_PIXELS;
}
```

drawLine():

```
void drawLine() {
static GLuint displayList = 0;

if (displayList)
{
    glCallList(displayList);
}
else
{
    displayList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(displayList, GL_COMPILE_AND_EXECUTE);
    glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT | GL_LIGHTING_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glLineWidth(2.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i += 2) {
        glVertex2f(vertices[i], vertices[i + 1]);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopAttrib();
    glEndList();
}
}
```

I numerated the tries of glRotatef() for different positions. I hope someone can give me a hint where my thought process went wrong.

Comment: You only have coordinates that have only 2 components (x, y). Then why do you swap y and z? This would make y become zero.

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) so you just swap the 2 columsn in your matrix ...

Comment: Thank your for your answers. My haptics device has 3 coordinates, even if im only using his x and y coordinates. Also those are the ones that i wanted to swap. Inserting hlRotatef() instead of glRotatef() fixed my problem. glRotatef() was rotate my openGL matrices instead of my touchworkspace matrix, so here was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Point the first: For the love of God USE SHADERS AND NOT OLD OPENGL.

With shaders, it is a trivial task of swapping 2 arguments, changing

```c
gl_Position = vec4(x, y, z, 1);
```

to

```c
gl_Position = vec4(x, z, y, 1);
```

I would recommend looking at [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiljJqr1rL6AhWNjokEHSKyCWgQFnoECBEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearnopengl.com%2FGetting-started%2FShaders&usg=AOvVaw31RtYzMPYvWPvBbrc6W5Uk) tutorial for shaders.

Other that that, in my opinion the code looks like it should work, but if it doesn't I know how finicky `glRotate` can be, so I really have no advice other that to try things until it works.

Sorry I couldn't give a full, direct answer.